# OpenGL "Layered" Conditional/Relative Transparency in 3D Space (Java)

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to learn about OpenGL as a hobby and to that end, I am trying to make a mod for the game *Minecraft* (a voxel game) which adds blocks that are uniquely rendered.

In the game, there are both opaque and translucent blocks rendered with quads. As to render transparency properly, the game first renders the opaque blocks and then renders the translucent blocks that have been sorted by distance. As such, they are classified separately by the game and are rendered separately by the rendering engine as different "RenderLayers"

For the purposes of my mod, I have created a separate render-layer that, when opaque blocks such as stone are set to be rendered in, will make those blocks translucent. Moreover, already translucent blocks will become more translucent in a multiplicative way. This was done through the use of a fragment shader applied to the whole layer.

So blocks that would normally render like this:

[image: Original rendering]

render like this when classified to the new render-layer.

[image: Modified rendering]

As seen in the picture, with the shader applied all blocks behind the now-translucent blocks became visible. However, this is not the behavior I desire. Instead, I would like the originally opaque blocks to obscure other blocks within the same render layer as if they were not translucent in the first place, though blocks from other "normal" render layers are able to be seen. Moreover, originally translucent blocks should still allow same-render-layered blocks behind to be seen.

In essence, I want to recreate the effect one would get had they merged two pictures taken with the different layers independently (with one at a lower opacity).

For example, with the above situation, it would be like this picture (normal layers):

[image: layer 1]

being overlaid with this picture (the special layer), with added transparency.

[image: layer 2]

to make this:

[image: correct]

As you can see, though the stone behind the stained glass retains a tint, the 2nd stone block behind the middlemost stone does not show in the final picture. This was done manually via merging photos in photoshop, but this "effect" is what I desire for my mod.

How would this be possible with OpenGL?

Clarification:

In the above image examples,

- the stone block is classified into the "special layer"
- the blue stained glass block is also classified into the "special layer"
- the surrounding grass blocks and the yellow concrete block is part of the "normal" layers

Comment: Sorry about the long post. I am new to computer graphics and so I didn't know how to describe this effect concisely.

Comment: I think it could be done by sorting this layer *in reverse*. Whether it's possible in Minecraft, I can't tell you.

Comment: Sounds like you want to render into a texture and then blend it as a post-processing step.

Comment: Pretty much, but I don't know how to do that (if possible)

Comment: ```In essence, I want to recreate the effect one would get had they merged two pictures taken with the different layers independently (with one at a lower opacity).``` - It sounds like a framebuffer using: 1) Render a some blocks to custom framebuffer with default scene settings 2) Render a full-screen quad with a transparency(attributed of vertices) with a custom framebuffer as a texture